# Why I am getting an Access violation exception?

Tags: assembly, x86, access-violation

I am trying to make a messagebox in pure assembly. Here are the steps I have taken so far:

**Find kernel32.dll base address**:

```
xor ecx, ecx
mov eax, fs:[ecx + 0x30]  ; EAX = PEB
mov eax, [eax + 0xc]      ; EAX = PEB->Ldr
mov esi, [eax + 0x14]     ; ESI = PEB->Ldr.InMemOrder
lodsd                     ; EAX = Second module
xchg eax, esi             ; EAX = ESI, ESI = EAX
lodsd                     ; EAX = Third(kernel32)
mov ebx, [eax + 0x10]     ; EBX = Base address
```

**Find the export table of kernel32.dll:**

```
mov edx, [ebx + 0x3c] ; EDX = DOS->e_lfanew
add edx, ebx          ; EDX = PE Header
mov edx, [edx + 0x78] ; EDX = Offset export table
add edx, ebx          ; EDX = Export table
mov esi, [edx + 0x20] ; ESI = Offset names table
add esi, ebx          ; ESI = Names table
xor ecx, ecx          ; EXC = 0
```

**Find GetProcAddress function name:**

```
Get_Function:
inc ecx                              ; Increment the ordinal
lodsd                                ; Get name offset
add eax, ebx                         ; Get function name
cmp dword ptr[eax], 0x50746547       ; GetP
jnz Get_Function
cmp dword ptr[eax + 0x4], 0x41636f72 ; rocA
jnz Get_Function
cmp dword ptr[eax + 0x8], 0x65726464 ; ddre
jnz Get_Function
```

**Find the address of GetProcAddress function:**

```
mov esi, [edx + 0x24]    ; ESI = Offset ordinals
add esi, ebx             ; ESI = Ordinals table
mov cx, [esi + ecx * 2]  ; CX = Number of function
dec ecx
mov esi, [edx + 0x1c]    ; ESI = Offset address table
add esi, ebx             ; ESI = Address table
mov edx, [esi + ecx * 4] ; EDX = Pointer(offset)
add edx, ebx             ; EDX = GetProcAddress
```

**Find the LoadLibrary function address:**

```
xor ecx, ecx    ; ECX = 0
push ebx        ; Kernel32 base address
push edx        ; GetProcAddress
push ecx        ; 0
push 0x41797261 ; aryA
push 0x7262694c ; Libr
push 0x64616f4c ; Load
push esp        ; "LoadLibrary"
push ebx        ; Kernel32 base address
call edx        ; GetProcAddress(LL)
```

**Load user32.dll library:**

```
add esp, 0xc    ; pop "LoadLibraryA"
pop ecx         ; ECX = 0
push eax        ; EAX = LoadLibraryA
push ecx
mov cx, 0x6c6c  ; ll
push ecx
push 0x642e3233 ; 32.d
push 0x72657375 ; user
push esp        ; "user32.dll"
call eax        ; LoadLibrary("user32.dll")
```

**Get MessageBoxA function address:**

```
add esp, 0x10; Clean stack
mov edx, [esp + 0x4]; EDX = GetProcAddress
xor ecx, ecx; ECX = 0
push ecx
mov ecx, 0x6141786f; aAxo
push ecx
sub dword ptr[esp + 0x3], 0x61; Remove "a"
push 0x42656761; Bega
push 0x7373654d; sseM
push esp; "messageboxa"
push eax; user32.dll address
call edx; GetProc(messageboxa)
```

**Call MessageBoxA function:**

```
add esp, 0x14; Cleanup stack  <-----was 0x10 in my OP, corrected this
xor ecx, ecx; ECX = 0
push 0x0; mb_icon_ok
push 0x0; text
push 0x0; title
push 0x0; hwnd
call eax; call messageboxa
```

**Get ExitProcess function address:**

```
add esp, 0x10; Clean stack
pop edx; GetProcAddress
pop ebx; kernel32.dll base address
mov ecx, 0x61737365; 
push ecx
sub dword ptr[esp + 0x3], 0x61; Remove "a"
push 0x636f7250; corP
push 0x74697845; itxE
push esp
push ebx; kernel32.dll base address
call edx; GetProc(Exec)
```

**Call the ExitProcess function:**

```
xor ecx, ecx; ECX = 0  <-----exception raised here
push ecx; Return code = 0
call eax; ExitProcess
```

I know this is a lot to go through, but it'd be nice if someone could help me understand. I am still new to this.

EDIT: updated code now it makes only one messagebox and a new exception arises:

> Unhandled exception at 0x002D8000 inMsgBoxShell.exe : 0xC0000005 :
> Access violation writing location 0x00000001.

Comment: Your comments are sometimes mismatched. Anyway one problem is the `add esp, 0x10; Cleanup stack` after getting the messageboxa address. You have pushed more than `0x10` bytes. If I read it correctly `0x1c` would work better but it's hard to follow what you are doing. PS: this is advanced programming, you are expected to be able to use a debugger so you can see what is wrong yourself.

Comment: 0x1c?? i see 0x14 which appears to be working

Comment: If it works, fine. But I see 6 pushes in that block and then `GetProcAddress` is still at `[esp+4]` so you need to remove 4 more bytes before you can `pop edx; GetProcAddress` later. So that's `0x1c`.

Comment: hmm strange when i run it in Release target it runs without crashing but in Debug i'm still getting an exception anyway something is wrong because process ends with code 1 even if it doesn't crash

Comment: The new crash is consistent with the wrong stack cleanup not allowing you to get the `ExitProcess` address.

Comment: Ok I forgot these functions were `stdcall` so yeah `0x14` is correct there. However `MessageBoxA` is also `stdcall` meaning that also removes all its arguments so you don't need the `add esp, 0x10; Clean stack` after it.